# Проблемы с кодировкой и поиск решения для множества запросов

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, cheerio

Есть такой код:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
let link = 'https://www.finanzen.net/bilanz_guv/exelon';

const parseFinanzen = async () => {
  
  try{
  
    await axios.get(link)
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(res => {
      
        let html = res;
        $ = cheerio.load(html);
        
        let outputFinanzen = $('.box.table-quotes:nth-child(1) table.table tbody tr:first-child').each(function(i, elem) {
          
          let subContent = $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').text();
          console.log(subContent);
        });
        
      }) 
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  
  catch(e){
    console.log("err- ", e);
  }
};

parseFinanzen();
```

В результате работы которого, я получаю следующий ответ - c не корректным символом '?':

> Ergebnis je Aktie (unverw�ssert, nach Steuern)

Вопросы:

1. Возможно ли исправить кодировку на UTF-8(к примеру) во время(или до) приема получения данных?
   (если да - то что конкретно и где необходимо прописать в текущей реализации, либо как ее можно модифицировать, что бы данное решение стало возможным?)
2. Если потребуется обращаться ко множеству ресурсов(а не к одному источнику) с которых необходимо спарсить данные - какой подход(вызова запросов) будет являтся наиболее корректным?
   (если есть по рукой примеры - буду благодарен за их демонстрацию.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574127/node-js-cheerio-parser-breaks-utf-8-encoding

Comment: http://joxi.ru/12MgEPYhkMeEdr
решение с данного поста не является рабочим.